# Imported SVN repository doens't show on gitlab

Tags: git, svn, gitlab, subgit

I'm importing a SVN repository to a gitlab linux server, and after it was configured and imported it doens't shows up on my gitlab page. What else do I need to do?

This is for a gitlab bitnami debian linux server pre-fabricated virtual machine using Virtual Box.
The gitlab web interface and repository creation works perfectly but after following the steps from https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/import/svn.html#smooth-migration-with-a-gitsvn-mirror-using-subgit the repository doens't appears.

This are the commands I executed in order:

To start the gitlab

```
cd /home/bitnami/stack
sudo ./ctlscript.sh start
```

To download the subgit

```
cd ..
wget https://subgit.com/files/subgit-3.3.6.zip
unzip subgit-3.3.6.zip
```

To install the needed packages

```
sudo apt-get install default-jre
sudo apt-get install git
```

To use the subgit

```
cd subgit-3.3.6/bin
sudo su git
./subgit configure --layout auto svn://192.168.0.1 /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/root/alternativa.git
./subgit import /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/root/alternativa.git
```

I expect a working repository on gitlab web interface but got a folder with apparently all the info needed but no repository ready to use on gitlab

Answer (score 2):

It's a known problem: GitLab uses caches when displaying Git repository content, so the external changes don't immediately show in the UI.

The possible work-arounds are:

1. If you were using continuous synchronization feature of SubGit then it would be enough to push something into the Git repository at least once. In this case SubGit hooks would be triggered and they will take care about all future UI updates.
2. If you don't use continuous synchronization feature (your case), you can run

```
gitlab-rake cache:clear
```

command on behalf or `root` system user. This would force updating the caches once. Pushing into the Git repository would also work.

I'm one of SubGit developers.

Comment: The gitlab-rake cache:clear didn't worked and I can't or don't know how to push into this repository, I'm inside of alternativa.git and the git status command shows only that the operation must be done in a work tree